# How do you init a new Mercurial project with a different username?

Tags: mercurial

Normally I would do this to start a new Mercurial project:

```
cd /project-directory
hg init
```

This uses the username that is set somewhere on my machine (`%USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini`)

But on this occasion I want to initialize a project with a different username.

Is there an option to use with `hg init` to do this?

Answer (score 9):

`hg init` doesn't use the username at all (repo starts with no changesets, at revision `null`). If you want to commit with a different username, use `hg commit --user`.

You can also set the username in the repository's hgrc (`.hg/hgrc`), just like you do in global one — then all commits to that repository will use it.